# JProfiler: Help in Step by step guide to integrate jprofiler on remote server ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tomcat7, jprofiler

I am trying to profile a remote server running tomcat7 on ubuntu. I have read multiple tutorials but not able to run it.

**JProfiler integration on remote server**

First I **downloaded** [jprofiler9](http://download-keycdn.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/jprofiler_linux_9_2.tar.gz) and **extracted** on remote system.

```
wget http://download-keycdn.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/jprofiler_linux_9_2.tar.gz
tar -xzf jprofiler_linux_9_2.tar.gz
```

and ran following command

```
jprofiler9/bin# ./jpintegrate
```

It asked me few information and generated 2 files

1. **startup-jp.sh** This file I guess is created from `startup.sh`, as the above wizard asked me to provide path to startup script (/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh) so new file is created in the same folder.
2. **config-jp.xml** The same wizard asked me to enter the name of configuration file with some instructions: can be imported in a
   JProfiler GUI to quickly connect to the application server

The changed contents startup-jp.sh are as follows

```
# The following lines have been added by the
# application server integration wizard of JProfiler

CATALINA_OPTS="-agentpath:/home/ubuntu/jprofiler9/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port=8383 $CATALINA_OPTS"
export CATALINA_OPTS

# end of modifications

exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" run "$@"
```

**Statring JProfiler**
Here I am confused how to run jprofiler, I guess running startup-jp.sh will start the profiler

It runs successfully but when I connect to this remote server from my local system with JProfiler GUI, server genrates few errors about path not found

here the console log after running the startup-jp.sh

```
root# /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
JProfiler> Protocol version 55
JProfiler> Using JVMTI
JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
JProfiler> 64-bit library
JProfiler> Listening on port: 8383.
JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
JProfiler> Native library initialized
JProfiler> VM initialized
JProfiler> Waiting for a connection from the JProfiler GUI ...
JProfiler> Using dynamic instrumentation
JProfiler> Time measurement: elapsed time
JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled
Oct 28, 2016 4:27:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Oct 28, 2016 4:27:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Oct 28, 2016 4:27:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Oct 28, 2016 4:27:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Oct 28, 2016 4:27:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Oct 28, 2016 4:27:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Oct 28, 2016 4:27:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina initDirs
SEVERE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Oct 28, 2016 4:27:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/server.xml]
Oct 28, 2016 4:27:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina initDirs
SEVERE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Oct 28, 2016 4:27:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/server.xml]
Oct 28, 2016 4:27:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
JProfiler> Keeping VM alive until frontend disconnects.
```

Clearly its not able to view different required directories (strange), Please note I never ran startup.sh to start my tomcat7 but used `service tomcat7 start`, may be here is the problem. Here is my directory structure for tomcat7

**/usr/share/tomcat7/**

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Oct 28 04:21 bin
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   39 Feb 21  2014 defaults.md5sum
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2.0K Feb 21  2014 defaults.template
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Oct 10 06:06 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   53 Feb 21  2014 logrotate.md5sum
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  118 Feb 21  2014 logrotate.template
```

**/var/lib/tomcat7/**

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4.0K Apr 21  2016 common
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      12 Jun 19  2015 conf -> /etc/tomcat7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      17 Jun 19  2015 logs -> ../../log/tomcat7
drwxr-xr-x  3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4.0K Apr 21  2016 server
drwxr-xr-x  3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4.0K Apr 21  2016 shared
drwxrwxr-x  6 tomcat7 tomcat7 4.0K Oct 27 06:10 webapps
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      19 Jun 19  2015 work -> ../../cache/tomcat7
```

**Fixed** above exception by adding following line in startup-jp.sh

```
export CATALINA_BASE="/var/lib/tomcat7/"
```

Now it is able to locate the missing folder

**New problem**

Now the issue is my local jprofiler gui is taking too much time (like if i restart the script it captures few of the entries but soon after

> CPU usage for tomcat is 197.5% reveled by top command

and hence nothing else get loaded by local jprofiler GUI. I have no way to identify what is causing this much CPU usage.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 5496 tomcat    38  18 3005m 675m  17m S 197.5  9.0  21:09.55 java
```

Comment: For this new problem, please contact me at support@ej-technologies.com

Answer (score 0):

The integration has been done correctly and is working as intended.

According to the permissions in your filesystem, you must execute startup-jp.sh as root, so execute

```
sudo sh startup-jp.sh
```

Comment: I am already running this script with root user. I have just realized I am already your fan, and I have actually gone through your screen cast on youtube about jprofiler. Nice work, clear voice and very easy to understand for non-English speaker

Comment: @PHPAvenger Thank you!